# Flutter & Supabase - Sign in With Google on

Tags: flutter, supabase

I use the function provided by the supabase_flutter package (code below). Everything functions smoothly when I test the functionality on my laptop with the device connected. It also works on iOS version (debug and release modes),  however, upon releasing the app on the Google Store, I encounter the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: 

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, l5.b: 10: , null, null) at GoogleSignInApi.signIn(messages.g.dart:221) at GoogleSignInAndroid._signInUserDataFromChannelData(google_sign_in_android.dart:111) at GoogleSignIn._callMethod(google_sign_in.dart:278) at GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled(google_sign_in.dart:431)
```

**Expected:** Sign in with Google

**Error:** I got an error instead.

```
Future<AuthResponse> _googleSignIn() async {
    /// Web Client ID  registered with Google Cloud.
    const webClientId = 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';

    /// iOS Client ID registered with Google Cloud.
    const iosClientId = 'YYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com';

    late GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    } else {
      googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
        clientId: iosClientId,
        serverClientId: webClientId,
      );
    }
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
    final accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
    final idToken = googleAuth.idToken;

    if (accessToken == null) {
      throw 'No Access Token found.';
    }
    if (idToken == null) {
      throw 'No ID Token found.';
    }

    return supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
      provider: OAuthProvider.google,
      idToken: idToken,
      accessToken: accessToken,
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I have used the same  SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from Setup > App signing (Google Play Console) in **Login with Google - Android** OAuth client.

[image: Use]